# Non-archimidean valued field set of elements with value $\leq 1$ is its algebraic interger ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be an non-archimidean valued field with $\mid \cdot \mid_v$ the non-archimidean absolute value, let $\mathcal{O}_k$ be its ring of algebraic intergers and $\mathcal{O}_v=\{x \in K: \mid x\mid_v \leq 1 \}$.

I want to prove $\mathcal{O}_k = \mathcal{O}_v$

An absolute value is nonarchimidean if its an absolute value and also satisfies $\mid x + y \mid_v \leq max\{\mid x \mid_v , \mid y \mid_v\}$

Fist, to prove $\mathcal{O}_k \subset \mathcal{O}_v$ is pretty easy:

Let $x \in \mathcal{O}_k$ be nonzero, clearly for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}, n\in \mathcal{O_k}$:

$\mid n \mid = \mid \sum_n1 \mid \leq \mid 1 \mid$

then as $x \in \mathcal{O}_k$ there exists $a_{n-1},...,a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$x^n = a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+.....+a_1x+a_0$, then $\mid x^n\mid_v \leq max\{\mid a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\mid_v,....,\mid a_0 \mid_v\}$ lets say $\mid a_jx^j\mid_v$ is the maximum, so then

$\mid x^n \mid_v \leq \mid a_jx^j\mid_v \leq \mid x^j \mid_v$ since $a_j$ is an interger an any interger is valued less than $1$, and since $\mid x^n \mid_v \leq \mid x^j \mid_v$ and $j < n$, $\mid x \mid_v \leq 1$ and done.

But I am having problems with $\mathcal{O}_v \subset \mathcal{O}_k$, now you can prove that $K$ is the field of fractions of $\mathcal{O}_v$, and I am almost sure that $\mathbb{R}$ is not the field of fractions of its ring of algebraic intergers, so this leaves me to believe that you need to ask the field to be an algebraic number field.

But I still cannot figure out how to go about proving this inclusion, so an help would be appreciated on the proof, and if you need to ask the field to be an algebraic number field.

Comment: Your question has a few problems: don't confuse the absolute value with the valuation. "ring of algebraic integers" doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: @reuns, the ring of algebraic intergers is the set of all elements in $K$ that have a monic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ to which they are a root of. This set with the algebra in $K$ is in fact a ring, so I don't get why it does not make sense to you. I am not confusing value with valuation, Maybe I should have put ''absolute value" instead of value but that's it.

Comment: I agree with @reuns concerns here: how do you define the "ring of algebraic integers" of the valued field $\mathbb F_p((t))$?

Comment: @Mathmo123 I just did some searching and we are managing two different definitions of valued fields, yours seems to be the accepted one. I found the definition here: https://scholar.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/ashvin/files/ashvinswaminathan-juniorpaper.pdf ..... Page 4, DEFINITION 1. They define a valued field, as a field together with an absolute value.

Comment: You also need to be careful: $\mathbb Q$ is a valued field with the $p$-adic valuation, but $\mathcal O_v$ is $\mathbb Z_{(p )}$, not $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Mathmo123, again,I think we are discussing two different things. First, if we are talking about non-archimidean abs. values and you want to use the $p-$adic valuation, for it to be an counterexample (since I am talking about abs. values), we have to use the $p-$adic absolute value, which is different And with the p-adic absolute value what your stating is wrong. And again algebraic intergers is not the same as $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Mathmo123  But ok, your argument works, since in $\mathbb{Q}$ all algebraic intergers happen to be $\mathbb{Z}$, and given $p=3$, then $\mid \frac{3}{2} \mid_v = \frac{1}{3} < 1$, so it is a counterexample after all. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to show that $O_v$ is integrally closed in $K$ ? It is relatively easy to show that if $v(\alpha)<0$ then $\alpha$ can't be the root of a polynomial $\in O_v[x]_{monic}$ (try first with $O_v=\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}$)

Comment: @reuns, what I wanted to show is what is stated in the post, which is a bit stronger than itegrally closed, and it turned out to be false.